# Django-Haystack elasticsearch prefetch error

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

i'm new to haystack and elasticsearch, so sorry in advance for a possibly lame question

when trying to ./manage.py rebuild_index, i'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefetch'
```

all the dependencies are installed as described in the manuals, the configuration made properly for the current version of django-haystack (2.0.0-beta). the project lives on mac os x lion, python 2.7.1, django 1.4, elasticsearch 0.20.1, JVM: 20.12-b

i searched here and there but couldn't find anything on this error. please, help

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the requests library is not backwards compatible with the one that pyelasticsearch was written for. You can either downgrade the requests library to one that works with your installed pyelasticsearch or you can install pyelasticsearch from the sources on github.

https://github.com/rhec/pyelasticsearch

Comment: i've installed pyelasticsearch from source, and that have worked indeed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had that error when using pyelasticsearch version 0.2. When I upgraded to 0.3 the error went away. So I think the latest version works with the latest version of requests.