# Django-Haystack elasticsearch error in index_queryset

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

when trying to build indexes for elasticsearch on django-haystack, i get the error (full traceback below)

```
TypeError: index_queryset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'
```

It is on Python 2.6, Django 1.4, ElasticSearch 0.20.2. Previously i have encountered a similar [prefetch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004803/django-haystack-elasticsearch-prefetch-error), which was the case of version mismatch between pyelasticsearch and requests library. i've tried to downgrade requests to 0.13, but no effect. pyelasticsearch is currently 0.3

any help very much appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/src/django-haystack/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 184, in handle
    return super(Command, self).handle(*items, **options)
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in handle
    label_output = self.handle_label(label, **options)
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/src/django-haystack/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 210, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/src/django-haystack/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 239, in update_backend
    end_date=self.end_date)
  File "/var/www/myproj/myproj-env/src/django-haystack/haystack/indexes.py", line 157, in build_queryset
    index_qs = self.index_queryset(using=using)
TypeError: index_queryset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'
```

Comment: What version of Haystack are you using?

Comment: few months ago there was 1.0, this is what i'm having locally. the current version is 0.3 - this is what i've tried to get running on server. i've managed to solve the problem simply overwriting haystack sources of the <older 1.0> over <newer 0.3>. so, the conclusion: <older 1.0> works smooth with the latest versions of all prerequisites (pyelasticsearch, simplejson and requests), while <newer 0.3> doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the version of django-haystack. The current version is 0.3, while few months ago it was 1.0, which is a bit of misunderstanding.

My way to solve the problem is simple and straightforward - install the latest version (0.3), then get the older version (in this case - 1.0) and simply overwrite haystack sources.

the conclusion: "older 1.0" works smooth with the latest versions of all prerequisites (pyelasticsearch, simplejson and requests), while "newer 0.3" doesn't